# How do I open a Precompiled website project when everything has moved

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got an old precompiled website that used to be on OldServer/websites/address and the project was on OldServer/projects/location.

Last year, we migrated to a NewServer, and moved everything over maintaining the same directory structure.

Now I have to make a modification.  When I try and open the project, I get a "The project file OldServer/projects/location/ has been moved, renamed..." error window.

I still have the files, just can't open the project.

Is there any way to get open it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the solution directory in Explorer and show hidden files. There should be a `suo` file. Make a renamed backup of this and then delete the original. Open your solution again and see if that's fixed the issue. If it hasn't , you could make a backup of the solution file (`sln` extension), open the original file itself and manually edit the paths to match your new format.

Note that deleting the suo loses customized information and settings such as breakpoints, tasks etc...

Comment: Modifying .sln in Notepad worked.  I can deal with losing customizations.

Comment: If you don't delete the suo file, and only edit the sln file, your customizations should remain AFAIK. (Unless the modification generates a new suo file).

Comment: I haven't actually tested for that.  I just had to modify a constant (NOT SO CONSTANT was it!!)  so I didn't care to much.

Comment: Ah fair enough. It's constant 99% of the time... :)